# php unexpected output using str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

i'm having the following php code:

```
    $html = '<p>[tag]</p>';
    $test = "<a href='#'><div class='test'>button</div></a>";
    $html = str_replace("[tag]", $test, $html);
```

when using echo htmlentities($html) i'm getting the expected result:

```
<p><a href='#'><div class='test'>button</div></a></p>
```

but when echoing the $html, firefox renders it like this:

```
<p>
<a href="#"></a>
</p>
<div class="test">
<p></p>
```

which is very strange .. 
any ideas what's wrong?

thanks

**EDIT:** i found out that it's only wrong when checking with firebug. when displaying the browser's source, it show's up as expected. nevertheless, to the browser it seems to be invalid html markup ..

Comment: how did you check firefox **renders** it? did you use any tool (e.g. firebug etc) or just saw the plain html source.

Comment: you cannot add `ul`, `ol`, `div`, etc.. tags inside a `p` tag, use `span` instead

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you can't have block level elements inside inline elements. Similar to that you can't put a `<p>` tag inside a `<span>` tag.

> **HTML 4.01** specifies that `<a>` elements may only contain inline
>   elements. A `<div>` is a block element, so it may not appear inside an
>   `<a>`.

Comment: How does browsers' rendering logic relate to PHP's output?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Firefox is a browser that does what it feels like.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're showing "selected source code". In firefox, the selected source code is modified version with the standart usage rules. You can show retrieved DOM by using show page source.

Answer (score 0):

Please do me a favor: replace the div element with span and it will work.
Reasons:

1. Div Element Contain Line Breaks so a div inside a link seems firefox rejecting.
2. Plugins....Uninstall Plugins.

Do That And You are good to go :D

Comment: Reasonable solution, questionable justifications. Please try to format the answers properly (SO has nice markup tools), avoid unneeded wording and bring reference if required to justify claims. Welcome aboard :)